# Junk character appendind at end of string after memcpy in c

Tags: c, memcpy

I am learning C.
In below code, when I tries to do memcpy it added junk character at the end.
Not getting what i am missing.
Please help.

```
int threshold = passlen - type;
 printf("THRESHOLD: %d\n",threshold);
 printf("TYPE: %d\n",type);
 printf("decodedpass: %s len(decodepass): %d\n",decodedpass,strlen(decodedpass));
  strncpy(salt, &decodedpass[threshold] , type);
 printf("-------SALT: %s\n",salt);
  salt[type] = '\0';
 printf("-------LASTSALT: %s\n",salt);
  saltlen = strlen(salt);
 printf("-------SALTLEN: %d\n",saltlen);
  int len = saltlen + userpasslen;
 printf("-------USERPASS: %s\n",userpass);
 printf("-------LENSALTandUSERPASSLEN: %d\n",len);
  createpass = xcalloc(len, sizeof(char));
  memcpy(createpass, userpass, userpasslen);
 printf("-------len(createpass):%d userpasslen:%d len(salt):%d saltlen:%d salt:%s\n",strlen(createpass),userpasslen,strlen(salt),saltlen,salt);
 printf("-------CREATEPASSmemcpy1: %s\n",createpass);
  memcpy(createpass + userpasslen, salt, saltlen);
 printf("-------CREATEPASSmemcpy2: %s len(createpass):%d\n",createpass,strlen(createpass));
```

OUTPUT:

```
THRESHOLD: 20
TYPE: 8
decodedpass: G�f�ɴ�=-$�o�   :K���R12345678 len(decodepass): 28
-------SALT: 12345678
-------LASTSALT: 12345678
-------SALTLEN: 8
-------USERPASS: 1234567890123456
-------LENSALTandUSERPSSLEN: 24
-------len(createpass):16 userpasslen:16 len(salt):8 saltlen:8 salt:12345678
-------CREATEPASSmemcpy1: 1234567890123456
-------CREATEPASSmemcpy2: 123456789012345612345678� len(createpass):26
```

Comment: `createpass` is not a _string_.  Code failed to append a _null character_.

Comment: `strncpy(salt, &decodedpass[threshold] , type);` is strange. You are copiend `type` count of characters from `threshold` point inside `decodepass` pointer into `salt`. Also the output doesn't match the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have no a *null* charter at the end of string in memory. When allocating a memory, you must consider this case. Then, there are two way to fix your issue:

1)

```
createpass = xcalloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
memset(createpass, 0, len+1);
```

or

2)

```
createpass = xcalloc(len+1, sizeof(char));
memset(createpass, 0, len+1);  // option, because the 'sprintf' will fill a '\0' at the end of string automatically.
sprintf(createpass, "%s%s", userpass, salt);
```

Enjoy.